# Does Api Gateway allow post request without request body

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, web-services, api-gateway

I have created and enpoint that has path param as id and using that it fetches data from db and then posts the data from database using http. I am using AWS ApiGateway to manage this endpoint however, when I pass the id and try to test the endpoint on api gateway without request body or some random valid request body, it shows:

```
"errors": [
        {
          "title": "Error in API Gateway",
          "code": "DEFAULT_5XX"
        }
      ]
```

It also shows the following in the logs:

```
Illegal character in path at index 101: http://example.local/orders/items/create/{id}
```

Comment: Since I have changed the url the index 101 does not make sense. But it points to the path param that I have passed as id

Comment: Can you post the cURL equivalent of your request? If using Postman, on right side, under Send button, there is a `code` button. Also, in URL, can you replace whatever you want to hide with some char like `X` instead of deleting it so 101 makes sense?

Comment: And POST is allowed without body.

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'https://xxxx-xxxxxgroup.abc.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com:443/xx/xxxxxxxxorders/reqitems/create/1234'

Above is cURL. Below is Url that I passed with example value in error:

http://xxxxxxxxxx-appxxxxxxxx.env-xxxxxgroup.abc.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.local/xxxxxxxxorders/reqitems/create/{id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, we can do a POST on API Gateway without a body. The error is pretty clear, it is an illegal character in the path.

There is a [post on AWS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-character-error/) about this. The solution is to add a proxy path variable in the integration request pane such that it does not run any validation checking on this particular path of the path.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't added the method.request.path.id in my cloudformation file. It worked after adding the same